# Best representation of a polynomial as a linear combination of binomial coefficients

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

[Newton's interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series)
shows that every polynomial is a linear combination of binomial coefficients. For instance,
$$
\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}
= 0 \binom{n}{0}+1\binom{n}{1}+3\binom{n}{2}+2\binom{n}{3}
$$
Using Pascal's relation, this can be reduced
$$
\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}=\binom{n+2}{3}+\binom{n+1}{3}
$$
Is this the simplest  linear combination of binomial coefficients for that polynomial?

Here is another example:
$$
n^5-5n^3+4n = 120 \binom{n}{3} + 240 \binom{n}{4} + 120 \binom{n}{5} 
$$
can be reduced to
$$
n^5-5n^3+4n = 120 \binom{n+2}{5}
$$

Is there a systematic method to find these economical representations?

Comment: Examples from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2350033/589 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1851131/589. I've used this technique in several other answers here.

Comment: I do believe that the sum of n^2 is 1/4*${2n + 2}\choose{3}$

Comment: @Vasting, oh, right! Which is my point: how do we simplify linear combination of binomial coefficients? Please add your comment as an answer. It does answer half of my question.